# Чем отличается логическое ИЛИ от исключающее ИЛИ?

Tags: логика

Не могу понять чем отличается логическое ИЛИ от исключающее ИЛИ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

В целом это можно описать следующими таблицами истинности:

Таблица истинности для логического ИЛИ:

<kbd>`A`</kbd><kbd>`B`</kbd><kbd>`A or B`</kbd>

<kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd>   

<kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>   

<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>   

<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>

Таблица истинности для исключающего ИЛИ:

<kbd>`A`</kbd><kbd>`B`</kbd><kbd>`A xor B`</kbd>

<kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd>   

<kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>   

<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>   

<kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd>

Если на пальцах объяснять, то логическое ИЛИ будет истиной, когда хотя бы один из операндов — истина. Исключающее ИЛИ будет истиной, если операнды не равны, и ложью, если операнды равны.

Answer (score 3):

Легко запомнить: XOR дает ноль, когда нет альтернативы (0-0, 1-1)